# How to run a bat file with variable in path

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make an audit script and some of my existing scripts are .bat files that I want to run from powershell and check the output for success/failure.

I have tried using start-process, but I can't capture the output right.  The way I have seen output grabbed was by running the .bat by assigning it to a variable.  My path however starts with a variable drive letter (as it is run off a USB.

```
$batExample = $USB\Audit\Script\Agent.bat
```

is sort of what I want, but that won't run as it is an unexpected token.

Have tried

```
$batExample = "$USB\Audit\Script\Agent.bat"
and 
$batExample = "$USB"\Audit\Script\Agent.bat
```

I am new to powershell.  Is there an escape key I am missing?

I am sure it is a small syntax problem, but I have tried all the steps I can think of.  Thanks!

Comment: both of those last two look like they otta work. [*frown*] you may want to use the `Join-Path` cmdlet to build your path. it's also somewhat safer in that it understands path delimiters.

Comment: Can you explain that a bit more @Lee_Dailey.  I was looking into it and I don't quite understand why it is safer.  I am sure it is, but what is the difference?

Comment: the `*-Path` commands are aware of things like path delimiters and thus prevent you from accidentally leaving one out ... or adding too many. plus, you don't have to fiddle with the single/double quote stuff. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To invoke a batch file you need to prefix the path with `&`. Pipe the output to Out-String to capture it as a variable.

```
PS C:\_scripts> "@ECHO This is the sample output line 1`n@ECHO This is the sample output line 2" | Out-File test.bat -Encoding ascii
PS C:\_scripts> $testoutput = & ".\test.bat" | Out-String
PS C:\_scripts> $testoutput
This is the sample output line 1
This is the sample output line 2
```

This should work in your example:

```
$batExample = & "$USB\Audit\Script\Agent.bat" | Out-String
```

If you need the `ERRORLEVEL` from the batch file you can use the `$LASTEXITCODE` [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.0).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.